# HANDLE_MSG macro gives 'HANDLE_0xXXXX is undefined'

Tags: c++, winapi

When I try to use HANDLE_MSG macro in my window procedure I get the following error:

> Error: identifier "HANDLE_0xXXXX" is undefined

where 0xXXXX depends on what message I'm giving as a parameter to the macro (0x0010 for WM_CLOSE, 0x0002 for WM_DESTROY and so on).

I've not found even a single mention about similar problem while googling for help.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Preview for Windows Desktop (although the same happens in VS 2012 Express for WD) on Windows 8.

A code snippet:

```
#include "Precompiled Headers.hpp"    // includes i. a. Windows.h and windowsx.h

#include "MainWindowProcedure.hpp"

LRESULT __stdcall MainWindowProcedure(HWND mainWindow,
                                      UINT receivedMessage,
                                      WPARAM wordParameter,
                                      LPARAM longParameter)
{

    switch (receivedMessage)
    {

        HANDLE_MSG(mainWindow, WM_CLOSE, MainWindowOnClose);

        ...

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(mainWindow,
                                 receivedMessage,
                                 wParam,
                                 lParam);
        break;

    }

    return 0;

}

void MainWindowOnClose(HWND mainWindow)
{

    DestroyWindow(mainWindow);

}
```

Comment: `HANDLE_MSG` is defined in `windowsx.h`.  Are you sure you're including it via your .hpp?

Comment: It looks like `WM_CLOSE` macro is expanded before `HANDLE_MSG` macro. Possibly some problem with `#include` order in `Precompiled Headers.hpp`. Post this file contents, or just try to change the order of include lines.

Comment: Actually, the order of include lines doesn't matter. Bug in preprocessor? How HANDLE_MSG macro is defined in windowsx.h on your computer, can you post its definition?

Comment: HANDLE_MSG definition: #define HANDLE_MSG(hwnd, message, fn)    \
    case (message): return HANDLE_##message((hwnd), (wParam), (lParam), (fn))

Comment: Did you try it disabling the precompiled headers?

Comment: You could probably work around the problem by using `HANDLE_WM_CLOSE(mainWindow, wParam, lParam, MainWindowOnClose)` instead. The problem itself looks weird, still. Macro expansion should never precede token pasting. It looks like a compiler bug. Highly unlikely, and I've never seen this before (on VS 2012).

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and just expanded the Macro like these three examples show.

```
     //HANDLE_MSG(hwnd, WM_INITDIALOG, OnInitDialog);
case (WM_INITDIALOG) : return HANDLE_WM_INITDIALOG((hwnd), (wParam), (lParam), (OnInitDialog));
    //HANDLE_MSG(hwnd, WM_COMMAND, OnCommand);
case (WM_COMMAND) : return HANDLE_WM_COMMAND((hwnd), (wParam), (lParam), (OnCommand));
    //HANDLE_MSG(hwnd, WM_PAINT, OnPaint);
case (WM_PAINT) : return HANDLE_WM_PAINT((hwnd), (wParam), (lParam), (OnPaint));
```